# Can I load a transmission line to more than 10x surge impedance loading?

Tags: high-voltage, transmission-line, conductors

Assuming that I use a high temperature low sag line that can withstand 210°C [CIGRE](https://www.cigre.org/article/GB/new-technologies-materials-and-approaches-for-overhead-lines). These lines have a thermal limit around 20x surge impedance loading (SIL). If I use such line:

1. Do I still need to follow St. Clair line loadability curve (see the figure below)? What is the point of these line materials, if the line loadability curve cannot be exceeded for 50+ km lines?
2. Is this curve valid for meshed network? that is in a meshed network I need to ensure that every line never exceeds this practical limit?
3. Assuming that I have voltage regulating resources on the receiving side, how can I take this into account when drawing the St. Clair line loadability curve? I suspect that I need to assume that the voltage regulating resources don't exist at least during line-energizing or recovering from blackout, but I am not sure!

[image: St. Clair line loadability curve]

St. Clair curve is often called line loadability curve was first proposed in https://doi.org/10.1109/AIEEPAS.1953.4498751, and I read about it in chapter 5 of "J. Duncan Glover, Thomas Overbye, Mulukutla S. Sarma, Power System Analysis and Design, SI Edition, 6th Edition." There are numerous articles and research papers discussing the theory behind and the derivation of this curve, e.g., https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAS.1979.319410 and [Line loadability curve](https://electricalbaba.com/line-loadability-universal-line-loadability-curve/).

Comment: Can you define what is a St. Clair curve and what it is used for? How have you computed the curves shown in your post?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the interesting question. While I am no expert on the matter, I may have anecdotal notes and superficial observations to share. Judging by the question, you are an apprentice of the trade, and thus have more in the way of education on the subject than I have...

You have shared a link to the [article on Line loadability curve](https://electricalbaba.com/line-loadability-universal-line-loadability-curve/). That contains some neat explanation, including the distances (regions of the curve) that are mostly limited by heat-up (up to 80 km), acceptable voltage drop due to resistive loss (80 to 320 km) and reactance (above 320 km, the chart ends at 960 km). If you use transmission line material that tolerates higher temperature (other conditions equal, e.g. resistance per meter), this merely means that your cap on temperature gets higher, i.e. allows you to drive the line harder at the short distances (up to 80 km). It won't necessarily help you with the voltage sag at distances longer than 80 km. Note that the load values for distances within 80 km are generally "off the chart" in that chart at your link :-) I would expect the hyperbola to lean left and go flat in that region.

I'm wondering what you mean by "voltage regulating resources". Tapped transformers, some large consumers can be told to regulate load, small renewable generators can be switched on or off...? Or, do you mean e.g. the myriad of SMPS type consuming devices? Overall I'd say that "startup from black-out" is an interesting topic in itself - and, at the macro scale of a grid, probably quite complex. Startup consumption for various types of loads and consuming client organizations is generally an issue, and I'd hazard a guess that in a practical grid, when starting after an outage, this is addressed in part by staggered start-up of the grid's distribution branches / areas / populations of some convenient size, which can be arranged by the transmission and distribution network operators. Plus, e.g. here in Europe, if individual national grids start up in insular mode, they can be later phased together and the trans-european grid is thus re-instated.

What's the point of using high-temp conductors, if they're only relevant up to 50 or 80 km?
I'd say that they have quite some merit in the more populated parts of the globe. For instance here in CZ, 80 km is roughly the distance from the central part of the country to the perimeter/borders. I.e, the span is relevant (see also the next paragraph on practical meshed networks / grids). What makes high-temp conductors more relevant, is the opposition to building more pylons = more parallel lines, from the general public in populous modern democracies. Also purchasing or renting all the land costs money. You can only hang so many parallel conductors on a pylon. And, with the growth of renewables, which at this time seem to be very far from evenly distributed across geography, demand for transmission capacity is only growing. Again CZ is geographically located such that over the past decade or so, Germany and Austria sorely needed our transmission capacity to transport the wind-generated electricity from the north to the south, because Germany is struggling to keep pace and build transmission routes of their own. The practical hurdles with approving construction of more routes / pylons are similar in CZ/DE/AT. If you can increase capacity by allowing for a higher operating temperature, that's a low hanging fruit. And yes, it's a couple hundred km from the Baltic sea to Vienna - but the transnational grid can have local bottlenecks of a couple dozen km where a couple dozen % more capacity will help a lot in the short term.

As for capacity planning in a mesh network:
First of all I'd argue that traditionally, this has not been a perfect mesh. In the beginning, this was a collection of trees: stemming from large generators, distributing energy to consumers of various sizes. Starting from that initial concept, backbone lines were later upgraded to a redundant mesh topology. Generally, if you want a single line in a redundant pair to work as a backup, each line must be able to carry the full load. Now in a broader modern grid/mesh network with several large generators and many places of consumption, where the "redundant paths in the network" are many, it is indeed more of a quiz to plan capacity. In reality, the way I understand it, the whole network is never engineered as a green-field project. You always have some status quo to start from: an existing transmission network, an existing set of generators, consumer populations, measured load patterns, perceived bottlenecks. Based on the status quo, you upgrade existing routes and develop new ones. Each route takes years from planning to construction. In reality, the utility companies are "never finished" overhauling their networks - it's a continuous process.

Over the last decades, the national grids across Europe transitioned from insular operation with no renewables (probably also broken by the iron curtain) into a densely interlinked continent-level mesh, where electricity production and consumption gets balanced and traded across transcontinental distances.

I am somewhat conversant in industrial time sync, and I get in contact with people in the electric transmission and distribution utilities. And, on occasions I have silly questions :-) Such as: at 50 Hz, the wavelength in vacuum is 6000 km. Thus, 100 km of a transmission line corresponds to about 6 degrees of phase shift. Or about 27 degrees across our country. At a distance of lambda/2 = 3000 km, the signal arrives with inverted phase. At a distance of lambda/4 = 1500 km, the transmission line inverts impedance - such that, "an open end at the far end" appears as a short circuit to the signal source (generator), and vice versa. In general, as you get close to lambda/4, transmission line impedance starts to matter, and the DC-style relationships between voltage, current and power become quite funky. Which is probably another reason, why the Line Loadability Curve ends before 1000 km on the horizontal axis.

Now: having a dense mesh of transmission lines across the continent, how can this remain stable? What's the sense of striving for phase alignment? Note that the European electric network traditionally didn't use phase-shifting transformers very often. Instead, it generally relies on direct coupling (via substations). Only recently some phase-shifters were introduced at border crossings, as a measure to coerce your neighbors to transport more or less of your surplus electricity...
So, how does it even function, with phase apparently allover the place?

And the answer supposedly is: the phase spreads out. The transmission grid contains local sources (generators) of various sizes, and local consumption. An optimal mode of operation is, where electricity generated gets consumed not far from the local generator. Generators get synchronized such that they are preferably all in phase, and hopefully the load (consumption) will take care of the rest. Electricity produced in offshore wind farms in the baltic region technically does not flow all the way to Austria. It enters the grid indeed, but a lot of it is locally consumed, and only "the balance of generation vs. consumption" gets a shifted a little south.

I have to say that the explanation still gives me a bit of shivers. The RF engineer part of my personality keeps scratching my head, subliminally: how can a wave, worth 400 kV pure AC, just "vanish and spread out". Yes the RF impedance matching of generators to load is debatable, and all that jazz... but just imagine a 50Hz waveform traveling halfway across Europe: some 3000 km mean lambda/2, which is where the signal appears in counter-phase. A mesh with generators is IMO like a lake where someone has thrown multiple rocks into the water, and you watch the circles intersect and combine.

So anyway: the network is large, the generators are distributed, so is consumption, reportedly the phase effects don't matter.
And then you also have occasions, where the conditions of generation vs. consumption across the continent happen to coincide, setting a favourable stage for... interesting incidents. Such as, [the one on January 8th 2021](https://www.entsoe.eu/news/2021/01/26/system-separation-in-the-continental-europe-synchronous-area-on-8-january-2021-2nd-update/), where the trans-continental capacity across Europe got tested - and, a bottleneck was found, somewhere between Croatia and Serbia. Once the weak link broke (a protection device disconnecting an overloaded substation busbar), a cascade of other line disconnections happened, and the trans-European network broke into two pieces.

Expert commentards in the interwebs at the time explained, that there was a quiet overcast day in the UK and France over the Baltic sea, and some spare production capacity was available as far as in Turkey, which the brokers at the "energy market exchange" happily traded, and the Turkish power plants tried to deliver... all across Europe.
Again the conspiracy-loving RF HAM in me tends to cackle about *phase* transfer, all the way from Turkey to France. Perhaps the public has been misled about the purpose of the phase shifters at our (CZ) and Polish borders with Germany all along? ;-D
On a more serious note: I'd love to see all the joint trans-European long-distance transmission lines converted to HVDC. That would solve *all* the problems with imaginary impedance and wave effects. Interestingly to me, noone has suggested this yet. And, HVDC remains as ubiquitous as the Maglev railway tracks.

I've found some Bc theses related to the topic of blackouts and countermeasures and "starting from black", unfortunately in Czech language... not worth quoting a link here.
Apparently, management of electric grids gets lectured in EE colleges... the Bc thesis refers to some courses at the local EE uni.